# Max Expansion Depth in MVC with OData 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

Is there a way to set a global max expansion depth for all $expands in MVC 4 with OData 2? I know you can do `[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 0)]`, but it would be nice to not have to do that every time.